# Assigning from incompatible type

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

I'm getting a warning

```
Assigning to 'id<ToolManagerDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'ViewState *__strong'
```

on this line

```
viewState.toolManager.delegate = viewState;
```

the delegate is of type:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id<ToolManagerDelegate> delegate;
```

whereas viewState inherits from NSObject and has the following category

```
@interface ViewState (PTListener) <ToolManagerDelegate>
```

Where is the problem? ViewState implements the required interface, how do I make the compiler happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this:

`@interface ViewState (PTListener) <ToolManagerDelegate>`

is implemented in a category.

Make sure that the category file is also imported.